# Loading image by relative path name

Tags: java, image, url, javafx, loading

I have a typical problem which concerns a loading files from specific directory.

This is how looks like a tree of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbnkb.png

And it is a part of code which causes a problem:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "images/image.png"))
            );
```

Could anyone tell me how to load a 'image.png' picture and where is an error in this code?

Comment: Looks like *images* folder is not part of the build path of your project. Check at the generated jar and see if it contains this folder and its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start from the root of your jar with "/". What you are currently doing is getting it from a relative location (from the Main class location).

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(
        "/images/image.png")));
```

Comment: This will seek for absolute path.

Comment: Luiggi, I just assumed the title was what the Op was currently doing. But yes, what I suggested is for absolute paths.